# Molecular biology - fundamental questions

Tags: genetics

Basic Gene, Chromosome, Genome, Protein - how are they ordered?

Genes make up Chromosome, and Chromosomes make up a Genome...

So, where does Protein come into play?

What do you call Genes that are spliced together to form something new?

What do you call a variable inside a Gene?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SE! At Biology SE we appreciate some evidence of personal effort of the PO to answer the question. Without it, we may put the question on hold, giving you the chance to add some background information.

Comment: I have zero biology education and I am asking because the people that write stuff about such things are very verbose (needlessly so, just like writers for other things) when I just need a quick answer. I am in a circumstance where I must/should get this right. If you have a "for dummies" simple introduction link/answer that can answer the questions, then please post it.

Comment: Makes sense. Hope my answer helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *where does Protein come into play?*

**A Gene codes a protein.**

**DNA is transcibed into messenger RNA (mRNA). mRNA is translated into protein.**

> *What do you call Genes that are spliced together to form something new?*

**Genes are not spliced together. One single gene can consist of *introns* (intervening sequences) and *exons* (expressed sequences). Transcribed introns in the RNA are spliced out and the exons glued together to form a functional mRNA.**

> *What do you call a variable inside a Gene?*

**Genes are made up of *DNA*. DNA is made up of *nucleotides***.

Comment: +1 Just an interesting note (definitely an exception to the rule), in some organisms, exons from different primary transcripts from different genes can be ligated. This is known as trans-splicing.